# controller can not read env variables on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, unicorn, capistrano3

I used Capistrano 3 to deploy my Rails 4 app to amazon ec2.

Unfortunately, my app on ec2 can not read environment variables.
I've added my variables to `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/environment` and tried

```
# config/deploy/staging.rb
set :default_env, {
    ...
}
```

I can get my variables via `$echo $my_var` on command line interface and `ENV['my_var']` on rails console on my ec2 instance. However, whenever I head to pages that need to read environment variable, I got a http 500 error. According to the log, it seems that my controller can not read the env variable.

I've also rebooted my server and re-deployed many times, but there is no luck.

How can I make my server read the env variable properly?

by the way, I am using `unicorn (4.8.3)` and the `capistrano-unicorn-nginx (~> 3.1.0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've found a solution for this by now. I'll post a brief answer so maybe it benefits to others that google for this.

Because server environment varies so much from OS to OS, Capistrano wants to ignore it and isolate from it as much as possible. Here's a [link with more info](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#the-command-map). Also, it is probably that capistrano does not load `~/.bashrc`, [more info here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/). These are likely the reasons why your app could not read the environment.

I'm not sure why updating the `:default_env` option was failing. But that's also not the best way to solve this because you'd have to place credentials in a file that is version controlled.

A good way to solve the secret credentials problem is by using either [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) or [rails_config](https://github.com/railsconfig/rails_config) gems. You'll likely prefer the `dotenv` gem because it works with env vars.

Rails 4.1+, has the built in `secrets.yml` "feature" which is also fine and will probably be the standard moving forward. I wrote the [capistrano-secrets-yml](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-secrets-yml) plugin that works with this.